# React: Reuse component issue, how to deal with if the api json string is different between multiple files

Tags: reactjs, components

here is the issue: I have a reuse List component, and using json api to load the data, what if the string is different in multiple files?

for example:
json1:

```
[
    {
        "post_title": "title 1",
        "post_excerpt": "excerpt 1"
    }
]
```

json2:

```
[
    {
        "article_title": "title 2",
        "article_excerpt": "excerpt 2"
    }
]
```

my reactjs code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export default class List extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            title: '',
            paragraph: ''
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        $.getJSON(this.props.source, function(data) {
            var collection = data;
            this.setState({
                data: collection
            })
        }.bind(this))
    }
    render() {
        var results = this.state.data || [];
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    results.map(function(result) {
                        return (
                            <div key={result.id}>
                                <h2>{result.post_title}</h2>
                                <p>{result.post_excerpt}</p>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<List source='http://m.xxx.com/api/get_news'/>, document.getElementById('list'));
```

plz advise! thx!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's either post_title or article_title, in which case you can do

```
return (
    <div key={result.id}>
        <h2>{result.post_title || result.article_title}</h2>
        <p>{result.post_excerpt || result.article_excerpt}</p>
    </div>
)
```

Edit: If you dont know the appending name then

```
function getItem(obj, item){
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (i.indexOf(item) > -1) return obj[i];
    }
}

return (
    <div key={result.id}>
        <h2>{getItem(result, 'title')}</h2>
        <p>{getItem(result, 'excerpt')}</p>
    </div>
)
```

Note this is not the best solution, it's not nice at all for many reasons but if you insist to working around the backend devs then this will do.

Comment: hi Yang Li,

it's not always post_title or article_title, actually maybe this is random, because the api were provided by the back-end guys, they don't know when to use the same string format. 

So maybe next time they will using blog_title or blog_excerpt, how to solve this issue? thx